# SDL How to check if window is maximized or minimized

Tags: linux, sdl, minimize, maximize, borderless

I'm trying to make a borderless window that can be maximized and minimized, but I can't get any information on how to get the current state of the window (if it's minimized or maximized) and how to use it.

(edit) rough snippets of the code:

```cpp
SDL_Rect minimize_area = {0,0,20,20};
Button minimize_window_button = Button(minimize_area);

SDL_Rect maximize_area = {0,0,20,20};
Button maximize_window_button = Button(maximize_area);

SDL_Rect close_area = {0,0,20,20};
Button close_window_button = Button(close_area);

// Program loop
while ( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) ) {
    case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if (event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT) {
            mouse.updateMousePosition();
            if (close_window_button.mouseInDstRect(mouse.pos.x, mouse.pos.y)) running = false;
            if (maximize_window_button.mouseInDstRect(mouse.pos.x, mouse.pos.y)) {
                if (/* WAY TO KNOW IF THE WINDOW IS MAXIMIZED */) {
                    SDL_MaximizeWindow(window);
                } else {
                    SDL_RestoreWindow(window);
                }
            }
            if (minimize_window_button.mouseInDstRect(mouse.pos.x, mouse.pos.y)) {
                if (/* WAY TO KNOW IF WINDOW IS MINIMIZED or UNMINIMIZED */) {
                    SDL_MinimizeWindow(window);
                } else {
                    SDL_RestoreWindow(window);
                }
            }

        }

        SDL_Log("click!");
        break;
}
```

Comment: can you share some code ? and more details.

Comment: sure thing! See my github page. https://github.com/Carlo-Bagnoli/NNUI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SDL_GetWindowFlags()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowFlags), check the `SDL_WINDOW_MINIMIZED` & `SDL_WINDOW_MAXIMIZED` bits.

Comment: I used them, but they didn't do anything, that's why I made this page, I'mma test it more tho

Comment: That's a very rough representation of my problem, I didn't thought that it was a problem that was worth adding a piece of code.

Comment: I put if (SDL_GetWindowFlags(window) == SDL_WINDOW_MAXIMIZED) SDL_Log("Window is borderless!"); in the game loop, but nothing happens when I maximize the window

Comment: @CarloAugustoBagnoliGomez `SDL_GetWindowFlags()` contains more flags. You need to extract the `SDL_WINDOW_MAXIMIZED` and check for that. Put `if(SDL_GetWindowFlags() & SDL_WINDOW_MAXIMIZED == 1)`.